# Динамическая смена ui файлов в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Изучаю Qt, наткнулся на такую проблему. Мне требуется быстро менять ui файлы по ходу выполнения программы. В python это реализовано так:

`uic.loadUi("filename.ui")`

В документации я откопал QUiLoader, но не совсем понимаю, как с ним работать. У меня имеется абсолютно стандартная программа, основанная на QMainWindow (которую создает Qt Creator изначально). Дело в том, что большинство примеров идет на QWidget и мне не понятно, как переделать их под QMainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример из моей программки (ui файл в данном случае в ресурсах):

```
QUiLoader loader;

QFile file(":/Dialogs/QcMoreDlg.ui");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
moreDlg = static_cast<QDialog *>(loader.load(&file, this));
file.close();

moreDlg->findChild<QLineEdit *>("excellent")->setText(QString().number(waste_block.excellent, 'f', 2));
moreDlg->findChild<QLineEdit *>("good"     )->setText(QString().number(waste_block.good,      'f', 2));
moreDlg->findChild<QLineEdit *>("waste"    )->setText(QString().number(waste_block.waste,     'f', 2));
if(!waste_block.plotCurves)
    moreDlg->findChild<QRadioButton *>("allButton")->setChecked(true);
else
    moreDlg->findChild<QRadioButton *>("signButton")->setChecked(true);
```

Comment: А можете привести пример вместе с объявлением класса, переменных и т.п.?

Comment: Так QUiLoader и нужен, для того, что обойтись без класса, а всё делать на лету

Comment: Так а сам класс MainWindow у вас есть же. Я именно про него и говорю.

Comment: Есть, но при чём тут главное окно? Берите любой пример http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-mainwindow.html

Comment: Главное окно создает указатель ui, который и держит на себе интерфейс и все взаимодействия с ним. Как повлиять именно на него через loader.load(...)?

Comment: Через QUiLoader никак, QUiLoader служит не для изменения интерфейса, а для динамического создания виджета из ui-файла без компилятора UIC

Comment: А, что конкретно нужно менять в интерфейсе?

Comment: Надо просто менять ui файлы, как то было в питоне

Comment: я сомневаюсь, что в питоне можно просто менять ui-файлы, это надо в XML работать, с ui-схемой, это целый qt designer нужен

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-ui-file-format.html

Comment: Не понимаю, о чем вы. Я пользовался Qt Designer для питона. И смена ui происходит в одну функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, вам нужно сделать вот это:

```
void MainWindow::centralWidgetFromUi(QString path)
{
    // Окрываем файл *.UI для чтения
    QFile f(path); 
    f.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    // грузим виджет из UI
    QWidget* newWidget = loader.load( f, this ); 
    // Удаление старого центрального виджета
    delete centralWidget(); 
    // Устанавлиаем новый виджет в качестве центрально
    setCentralWidget( newWidget ); 
}
```

Comment: видимо да, не сам ui менять ему надо, а виджет другой грузить...